# searching in Perforce Visual Client

Tags: version-control, perforce, configuration-management, perforce-client-spec

I am new in perforce Visual Client and I am not able to figure out a very basic utility. I want to search my workspace for files which contain some specific words. I found out that at Edit  --> Find in File ---> there are two options Search in: and All or part of the file name:. But where do I set the filter that I only want to search files which contain specific words? I think the Perforce Visual Client should have this basic utility somewhere but maybe I'm missing it. Kindly help me to find this option. Your help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perforce visual client do not contain tool for searching files with specific content. You can use command line:

```
p4 grep -e compile_settings //Jam/MAIN/src/...
```

check http://www.perforce.com/blog/100712/p4-grep

Comment: And you can configure this as a custom tool if you want to launch it from P4V, using the selected directory and prompting for the search pattern.